# Cardano Node Causing Browser Errors

Tags: cardano-node, cardano-serialization-lib

I am not a developer, just a hobbyist.

I installed the Cardano Node (1.33.0-win64) so that I could point my Nami Wallet Browser Extension to it, rather than the web server node Nami points to by default. Ever since installing the node, I get browser errors that reference the Cardano Node and  "WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming" (full console error from dev tools below). Just visiting websites is all it takes to get the errors.

Can someone help me learn more about this, and perhaps point me in the direction to a solution? I could just uninstall the node, but I want to solve the issue.

Thank you!

cardano_serialization_lib.js:13074          GET https://www.google.com/wasm/csl-v10.0.4.wasm 404
cardano_serialization_lib_init @ cardano_serialization_lib.js:13074
(anonymous) @ CardanoSerializationLib.ts:11
(anonymous) @ CardanoSerializationLib.ts:15
(anonymous) @ dom-script.js:27
(anonymous) @ dom-script.js:27
cardano_serialization_lib.js:12883 `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming` failed because your server does not serve wasm with `application/wasm` MIME type. Falling back to `WebAssembly.instantiate` which is slower. Original error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status code is not ok
load @ cardano_serialization_lib.js:12883
await in load (async)
cardano_serialization_lib_init @ cardano_serialization_lib.js:13079
await in cardano_serialization_lib_init (async)
(anonymous) @ CardanoSerializationLib.ts:11
(anonymous) @ CardanoSerializationLib.ts:15
(anonymous) @ dom-script.js:27
(anonymous) @ dom-script.js:27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser or extension is trying to get the wasm code.

Your error shows `GET https://www.google.com/wasm/csl-v10.0.4.wasm 404`

The 404 result means 'not found'.

I found this reference: https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib/issues/398

Do you have Eternl wallet extension installed in your browser? Seems that it is using the wasm URL above and failing, so best to disable Eternl wallet extension and try again.

Keep in mind that browser extensions inject their code into every page that you visit, so if one extension is not working correctly the impact will be felt on every page that you visit.

Comment: I think this issue is being tracked on https://github.com/ccwalletio/tracker/issues/119. It is a pretty major bug introduced by this Wallet Browser Extension.

Comment: I disabled Eternl and that totally eliminated the error message! I thought it was the node this whole time. Thank you so much.